# My code based on a project in Treehouse.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote the code below based on a project in Treehouse.com:

```
class Buxfer
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @transactions = []
        add_transaction("Opening Balance", 0)
    end
    def add_transaction(description, amount)
        @transactions.push(description: description, amount: amount)
    end
    def credit(description, amount)
        add_transaction(description, amount)
    end
    def debit(description, amount)
        add_transaction(description, -amount)
    end
    def balance
        balance = 0.0
        @transactions.each do |transaction|
            balance += transaction[:amount]
        end
        return balance
    end
    def print_account
        puts "-" * 60
        puts "Account Holder Name: #{name}".ljust(30)
        puts "-" * 60
        puts "-" * 60
        puts "Description".ljust(30) + "Amount".rjust(30)
        puts "-" * 60
        @transactions.each do |item|
            puts item[:description].ljust(30) + sprintf("%0.2f", item[:amount]).rjust(30)
        end
        puts "-" * 60
        puts "Balance: #{balance}".rjust(60)
        puts "-" * 60
    end
end

helios = Buxfer.new("Helios")
helios.debit("Rent", 2000)
helios.debit("Food", 800)
helios.debit("Gym", 45)
helios.credit("Salary", 8000)
puts "\n"
puts "\n"
puts helios.inspect
puts "\n"
puts "\n"
puts helios.print_account
```

- Creating method `add_transaction`.

  It takes two arguments and `push`es them to the `@transactions`. I am not sure what happens with `(description: description, amount: amount)`. Is this a hash with a symbol as the key and the value as either a string or an integer?
- The `credit` (and `debit`) methods

  ```
  def credit(description, amount)
   add_transaction(description, amount)
  end
  ```

  I create the `credit` method that takes two arguments. Not sure what happens in `add_transaction`. It is pushed to `@transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

In `add_transaction`, look here:

```
 @transactions.push(description: description, amount: amount)
```

As initialized in your `initialize` method, `@transactions` is an Array (empty by default). [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) is a method that *Pushes the given object(s) on to the end of array*. This is what is adding your passed arguments to `@transactions` array. Since the arguments to `push` method are in key-value pair, the pushed object is a Hash.

Example to make it clearer:

```
@transactions = []
#=> []
@transactions.push(description: "somethign", amount: 100)
#=> [{:description=>"somethign", :amount=>100}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking example from your question itself:

```
helios = Buxfer.new("Helios")
helios.debit("Rent", 2000)
helios.debit("Food", 800)
helios.debit("Gym", 45)
helios.credit("Salary", 8000)
puts "\n"
puts "\n"
puts helios.inspect
puts "\n"
puts "\n"
puts helios.print_account
```

In this every time you do credit or debit the description and the amount gets added to the transaction object. It's basically pushing objects inside array, which you can loop later to get account balance as done in **print_account** method.
So the transaction object looks like this:

```
@transactions = [{description: 'Rent', amount: -2000}, {description: 'Food', amount: -800}, {description: 'Gym', amount: -45}, {description: 'Salary', amount: 8000}  ]
```